# Does CORS work with iOS emulator in Xcode?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I have an application that works fine with CORS and Safari. When i test it with the iOS 6 emulator in Xcode, it doesnt retrieve any data from my web service, but does so with Safari. (Im using PhoneGap aswell)

Is it because i have to set up something special with Xcode?

Answer (score -1):

I found my answer here:

http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/11/22/phonegap-gotcha-error-whitelist-rejection/

Solution:

```
In your PhoneGap.plist file, you need to add the allowed URLs to the ExternalHosts array. I added “*” as I did not want to add each individual URL separately to the list but that’s your choice.
```